# When should I use a comma before a prepositional phrase?

Tags: commas, prepositional-phrases

Can someone please give me some examples 
of when I should and should not use a comma before a prepositional phrase?

These are some of the sentences that I am having trouble with:

1. These are the problems that I've struggled with in my own life
2. I looked on the other side of me & seen a bird.
3. All of my friends came with me except Ron.
4. I want to help all of the people who have problems like I've had before.

Can someone show me which sentences need commas?
I need someone to show me where the commas need to go too!

Comment: Of course, you would not say "I looked on the other side of me and SEEN a bird."
It would be "I looked on the other side of me and SAW a bird."

Answer (score 3):

None of your examples needs a comma before the preposition.  All of the following would be nonsense:

> 2. I looked, on the other side of me and seen a bird.
>      I looked on the other side, of me and seen a bird.
>      I looked, on the other side, of me and seen a bird.
> 3. All, of my friends came with me except Ron.
>      All of my friends came, with me except Ron.
>      All, of my friends came, with me except Ron.
> 4. I want to help all, of the people who have problems like I've had before.

The only possible commas I could see (and they would be optional) are:

> 1. These are the problems that I've struggled with, in my own life.

> 3. All of my friends came with me, except Ron.

They are optional because they serve as a pause before a parenthetical expression.

Comment: Thank you for the awesome explanation. I appreciate all of the help!