# Commas before prepositions

Tags: grammar, prepositions, commas, prepositional-phrases

I refer to the example sentences given here (https://www.lexico.com/definition/except):

- ‘I looked around, but it was dark outside except for one street light at the corner a short way ahead of me.’
- ‘Everything is very quiet, except for the occasional floomfing sound of snow falling off pine trees and cedars.’

It seems that people sometimes use commas before prepositions or prepositional phrases, such as "except for". I have three questions:

1. When is a comma allowed before prepositions or prepositional phrases?
2. What is the grammatical rule behind this?
3. Is this related to essential vs. non-essential information?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use a comma before a prepositional phrase?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209067/when-should-i-use-a-comma-before-a-prepositional-phrase/209429#209429) eg 'All of my friends came with me except Ron.'

Comment: Thanks, I saw this answer previously, but I was not sure if "[commas] are optional because they serve as a pause before a parenthetical expression" explains the general rule. It doesn't state either which prepositions or prepositional phrases allow a comma before. May I kindly ask you to comment on that, please?

Comment: In your examples, I'd say the commas are optional, but I'd do exactly as in the examples. This is because it's easy to see where the sentence 'except for one street light' is continuing, so a pause to aid parsing isn't needed (and there's a commendable minimalist tendency with regard to comma use in recent times). However, 'except for the occasional floomfing sound of snow falling off ...' is far heavier, so a pause to grasp the sense of the sentence (and to breathe) is welcome. But hereabouts, commas are style choices. Do you want a pause? Or do you feel evil?

Comment: Thank you Edwin!:-)

Comment: On that note Edwin, can I also use a comma before "and" in cases like the following to create a pause and help the reader parse the sentence? Or would you recommend against it? I'm aware that a comma before 'and' should usually only stand in a list of more than two items (optional) or between independent sentences:

In the absence of any reference data, at least six sensors would be required so as to reconstruct a blade vibration signal at 420 Hz in the ideal world, and twenty sensors in the corresponding case of 1140 Hz.

Comment: (a) (and that should be a capital a). Know your audience. If you have a 90-year-old supervisor, you may be flogged for using a new (1970s) style of punctuation. (b) Punctuation 'rules' are often merely guidelines, and older 'rules' often didn't anticipate difficult areas where conflicts might occur. (c) Let's be fair, we don't want to be different just to show that we live in a democracy. Non-standard usages confuse and irritate. So (d) Clarity first, then non-outrageous usage (or is it the other way round?) Then, use commas to help parse, then to show where we fancy a pause. (e) USE one here!

Comment: Well and amusingly explained, thank you Edwin!:-)